# Google Sheets data validation: Allow only natural numbers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-data-validation

I am trying to do this simple thing in Google Sheets with data validation, so what I want to do is not allow people to put negative numbers and numbers with decimals.
I've been trying a lot of different things but still can't really figure out how to do it.

Comment: Welcome. Please be describe briefly what you already tried as well you search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

This could be done by treating the input as text, then validating that text against a regular expression.

To do so for cell `A1`, create a validation rule with the custom formula `=REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(A1); "^[1-9]+[0-9]*$")`
[image: Screenshot from Google Sheets]

Adjust `A1` in the formula to suit your needs.

This will accept any value which consists of digits only. If the user enters anything else (like `-`, `,` or `.`) the validation will fail. Also, the first digit cannot be `0`.

The regex explained: https://regexr.com/7aov7

Answer (score 0):

Pretty clear to me, just natural numbers. A quick way would be to have a column out of sight that holds from 0 to as many as you want, say 10000 and then set the data validation to that list of numbers. That way you force the values to be only the numbers contained in your list which happen to be the natural numbers from 0 to 10000.

Comment: zero is not a natural number, but you get the picture